# Can multiple RocksDB instances share and read from the same key-range?

Tags: rocksdb, okvs

Past answers on Stack Overflow suggest that the single threaded nature of RocksDB means the answer is no, but official FB documentation has pages like this http://rocksdb.org/blog/2021/05/27/rocksdb-secondary-cache.html where multiple instances seem to be sharing a cache.

1)Are these instances using the same key range?

2. If so, how are updates being communicated from one DB instance to another? As far as I know RocksDB doesn't have any interDB communication?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you have on rocksdb instance or several? Are they all in the same POSIX processus or thread. Do you share multiple rocksdb instance (same env) inside the same POSIX processus? Please give more context.

Comment: @amirouche What I'm trying to understand is how multiple instances of RocksDB that share a secondary cache are connected? Are they in the same POSIX process? And do they they logically operate on the same set of files in secondary cache or is it partitioned between each instance.

Comment: What do you mean "single threaded nature of RocksDB"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. DB instances do not share key range.

Just FYI. one process can have multiple RocksDB instances, each instance can have multiple column-families. They do not share user-data. Internally, column-families in one instance share WAL (write ahead log), manifest (tracking db information), option file. DB instances in one process share the same Env, threadpool, timer, cache.